# How to fix memory leak in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [passConf, setPassConf] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [usersRef, setUsersRef] = useState(null);

  const isPasswordValid = () => {
    if (password.length < 6 || passConf.length < 6) {
      return false;
    } else if (password !== passConf) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

  const isFormValid = () => {
    let errors = [];
    let error;

    if (!isPasswordValid()) {
      error = { message: "Password is invalid" };
      setErrors(errors.concat(error));
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

  const saveUser = (createdUser) => {
    setUsersRef(firebase.database().ref("users"));
    return usersRef.child(createdUser.user.uid).set({
      name: createdUser.user.displayName,
      avatar: createdUser.user.photoURL,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isFormValid()) {
      setErrors([]);
      setLoading(true);
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((createdUser) => {
          console.log(createdUser);
          createdUser.user
            .updateProfile({
              displayName: username,
              photoURL: `https://gravatar.com/avatar/${md5(
                createdUser.user.email
              )}?d=identicon`,
            })
            .then(() => {
              saveUser(createdUser).then(() => {
                console.log("user saved");
                setLoading(false);
              });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              setLoading(false);
              setErrors(errors.concat(err));
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setLoading(false);
          setErrors(errors.concat(err));
        });
    }
  };

  const displayErrors = (errors) =>
    errors.map((error, i) => <p key={i}>{error.message}</p>);

  return (
    <Grid textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" className="app">
      <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
        <Header as="h2" icon color="orange" textAlign="center">
          <Icon name="rocketchat" color="orange" />
          Register for Super Chat
        </Header>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} size="large">
          <Segment stacked>
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              name="username"
              icon="user"
              iconPosition="left"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
              value={username}
              required
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              name="email"
              icon="mail"
              iconPosition="left"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={email}
              required
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              name="password"
              icon="lock"
              iconPosition="left"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              required
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Form.Input
              fluid
              name="passConf"
              icon="repeat"
              iconPosition="left"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password Confirmation"
              value={passConf}
              required
              onChange={(e) => setPassConf(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button disabled={loading} color="orange" fluid size="large">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Segment>
        </Form>
        {errors.length ? (
          <Message error>
            <h3>Error</h3>
            {displayErrors(errors)}
          </Message>
        ) : null}
        <Message>
          Already a user? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </Message>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I am not able to find where this memory leak is happening.
I am able to sign in with one account but after signing out and signing in again with another account, it's giving this warninng and firebase realtime database is also not updating.

How can I fix memory leak here?